# Rails:: run migration without test group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Rails 3.*

Shouldn't it have something `rake db:migrate --skip test` or something equivalent.

I want to skip test group in production.

Comment: Have you tried this `rake db:migrate -e production --skip test`

Comment: not working ,even I tried `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --skip test`
invalid option: --skip

Comment: try this `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --without test`

Comment: invalid option: --without

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_WITHOUT=test rake db:migrate`